# Insert data in database when corresponding check box is selected using Jquery, Ajax and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, checkbox

I have little form with a couple of check boxes and a hidden div which opens when user check  corresponding box. I want to use ajax and json to insert the data in database when speccific date is checked and to insert time in database inserted from hidden div. Is it possible?
Here is my form: 
[ON jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oksidans/csSNY/4/)

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="monday" id="mon" class="toggler"  /> Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" id="tue" class="toggler"  />Tuesday
<input type="checkbox" name="wendsday" id="wen" class="toggler"/> Wendsday
<input type="checkbox" name="thursday" id="thu" class="toggler"  /> Thursday
<input type="checkbox" name="friday" id="fri" class="toggler" /> Friday
<input type="checkbox" name="saturday" id="sat" class="toggler" /> Saturday
<input type="checkbox" name="sunday" id="sun" class="toggler" /> Sunday
</div>
    <div id="name" class="hidden" style="display: none">
    Time From::<input type="text" id="place" placeholder=""></input> Time To::<input type="text" id="place_one" placeholder=""></input>
    <input type="button" onclick="save_time();" value="Save" />
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(id){
       if (this.checked) {
           $('#name').slideDown();
       } else {
           $('#name').slideUp();
       }
   });

   save_time = function(days){
       $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "",
          data: "days="+days,
          success: function(data){

          }
       });
       $('#name').slideUp();

   };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a few things in your fiddle to correctly pass the 'day' + added the 'from' and 'to' values to the post data. Also, currently only one day can be selected at once because I guessed this is required by your logic.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csSNY/10/).

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(id){
       $('.toggler').not('#' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('checked', false);
       if (this.checked) {
           $('#name').slideDown();
       } else {
           $('#name').slideUp();
       }
   });

   save_time = function(){
       var id = $('.toggler:checked').attr('id');
       $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "url",
           data: {day: id, from: $('#place').val(), to: $('#place_one').val()},
          success: function(data){

          }
       });
       $('#name').slideUp();

   };

});
```

Comment: thank you @Marcell Fülöp This is the idea that i needed. Now i just have to figure it out how to do it in php. Thanks again :)

Comment: Now when using PHP on server-side, you'd receive $_POST['day'], $_POST['from'] and $_POST['to']. Of course you can change the post paramter names in JS. You can access and validate these POST variables and then save them according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the contentType and dataType attribute of ajax call.

```
save_time = function(days){
           $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "",
              data: "days="+days,
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data){

              }
           });
```

and in your server side method should have attribute like this

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string MethodName(string days)
    {
        // your code
    }
```

Comment: Content-Type is automatically set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for POST requests if not specified. `dataType` is also guessed by jQuery if specified in the response.